# Omit type annotations for local variables

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my code

```
print('Please enter a number');
int number  = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync());
print('Your number is $number');
```

and I have this error : `Omit type annotations for local variables`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `'` at the end of `$number`.

Try this:

```
  print('Please enter a number');
  int number  = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync());
  print('Your number is $number');
```

**NOTE:** That code will work only when the `stdin.readLineSync()` is an `integer`. The code will fail if the `stdin.readLineSync()` is a `double`.

To keep it save, I highly recommend to use `double`, like this:

```
  print('Please enter a number');
  double number  = double.parse(stdin.readLineSync());
  print('Your number is $number');
```

So, the code will works if the value of `stdin.readLineSync()` is a `double` or `integer`.

I hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an error, just a warning message.

To correct this error , just replace the `int` by `var`

```
var number= int.parse(stdin.readLineSync());
```

Comment: why is it better to use untyped local variables?

Answer (score 0):

Its the 'default' google analyser settings emit the warning

To remove this warning by the Lint rule, give a proper variable name with a correct datatype. You can change the datatype with the following changes

1. If you are not reassigning value again in a variable change its data type to `final`.
2. If unsure which value to assign, you can make it `var` and reassign a new value again.
3. And if you are sure with the datatype and want to reassign a new value in the variable use the datatype with a null operator `bool? isCorrectValue = false;`

For further information you can read this [issue](https://github.com/google/pedantic/issues/45)